# Loop results in wrong position/order

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I need to calculate the results of a very simple formula (weighted average) that uses two variables (A and B) and two weight factors (A_prop and B_prop). The calculation is to be performed in a very large data set and the weight factors are stored in another data frame that I called here grid.

My approach was first to create repetitions of the data for each weight factors combination and then performed the calculations. Till that nothing strange. However then I thought about calculating values inside loop. Everything seemed to be in place, but then I checked the results of both approaches and results do not match. The results from the calculation inside loop are incorrect.

I know I should just get along and keep with the one that gives me the correct results, also because the number of lines are quite small. No big problem. However... I can just live with this. I'm about to tear my hair.

Can anyone explain me why the results are not the same? What's wrong with the loop calculation?
Also, in addition, if you have any suggestion on a more elegant it will be welcome.

(note: my first time using a reprex. Hope it is as it should)

```
>require(tidyverse)
>require(magicfor)
>require(readxl)
>require(reprex)

> dput(dt)
structure(list(X = 1:5, A = c(83.73, 50.4, 79.59, 62.96, 0), 
    B = c(100, 86.8, 80.95, 81.48, 0), weight = c(201.6, 655, 
    220.5, 280, 94.5), ind = c(733L, 26266L, 6877L, 8558L, 16361L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

> dput(grid)
structure(list(A_prop = c(0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 
0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1), B_prop = c(0.5, 0.45, 0.4, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 
0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0), id = 1:11, tag = structure(1:11, .Label = c("Aprop_0.5", 
"Aprop_0.55", "Aprop_0.6", "Aprop_0.65", "Aprop_0.7", "Aprop_0.75", 
"Aprop_0.8", "Aprop_0.85", "Aprop_0.9", "Aprop_0.95", "Aprop_1"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

> foo<-function(data,i){
+   val<-(data$A*grid[i,1])+(data$B*grid[i,2])
+   return(val)
+ }

> magic_for(print, progress=FALSE,silent = TRUE)

> for(i in grid$id){
+   
+   score<-(dt$A*grid[i,1])+(dt$B*grid[i,2])
+   
+   weight=dt$weight
+   A<-dt$A
+   B<-dt$B
+
+   ind=dt$ind
+
+   print(score)
+   print(weight)
+   print(ind)
+   print(A)
+   print(B)
+ }

> rest<-magic_result_as_dataframe()

> magic_free()

> rest2<-left_join(rest,grid,by=c("i"="id"))%>%
+   arrange(ind,tag)%>%
+   mutate(score2=(A*A_prop)+(B*B_prop))

> head(rest2)
  i   score weight ind     A   B A_prop B_prop        tag  score2
1 1 91.8650  201.6 733 83.73 100   0.50   0.50  Aprop_0.5 91.8650
2 2 84.5435  201.6 733 83.73 100   0.55   0.45 Aprop_0.55 91.0515
3 3 86.1705  201.6 733 83.73 100   0.60   0.40  Aprop_0.6 90.2380
4 4 87.7975  201.6 733 83.73 100   0.65   0.35 Aprop_0.65 89.4245
5 5 89.4245  201.6 733 83.73 100   0.70   0.30  Aprop_0.7 88.6110
6 6 91.0515  201.6 733 83.73 100   0.75   0.25 Aprop_0.75 87.7975
```

Comment: Please provide the code in an appropriate format. The for loop is truncated....

Comment: Sorry. Didn't notice it. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually your left_join and NOT the for loop. For future posts, I would recommend that you also provide a minimal(istic) example.

I will demonstrate what went wrong in your code.

Say, we have these data frames, which should be similar to your real-world data:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  A = c(2,3,4),
  B = c(20,30,40)
)

grid <- data.frame(
  A_prop = c(0.5, 0.6),
  B_prop = c(0.5, 0.4),
  id = c(1,2),
  tag = c("A_prop0.5", "A_prop0.6"))
```

We expect the following outputs:

Expected Output dt[1,] & A_prop 0.5 and B_prop 0.5

2 * 0.5 + 20 * 0.5 #= 11

Expected Output dt[2,] & A_prop 0.5 and B_prop 0.5

3 * 0.5 + 30 * 0.5 #= 16.5

Expected Output dt[3,] & A_prop 0.5 and B_prop 0.5

4 * 0.5 + 40 * 0.5 #= 22

Expected Output dt[1,] & A_prop 0.6 and B_prop 0.4

2 * 0.6 + 20 * 0.4 #= 9.2

Expected Output dt[1,] & A_prop 0.6 and B_prop 0.4
 3 * 0.6 + 30 * 0.4 #= 13.8

Expected Output dt[1,] & A_prop 0.6 and B_prop 0.4

4 * 0.6 + 40 * 0.4 #= 18.4

I have never used the "magicfor" library, but the problem lies in your way of joining `i` and `id`.

I would write the for loop as follows:

```
l <- list()
for(i in grid$id){
  score<-(dt$A*grid[i,1])+(dt$B*grid[i,2])
  A<-dt$A
  B<-dt$B
  iteration <- rep(i, 3) # to keep track in which iteration the result was created.
  l[[i]] <- list(
    score = score,
    A = A,
    B = B,
    iteration = iteration
  )
}
```

Now I bind the list to a data frame and do the left_join as you did in your example:

```
l <- bind_rows(l)

l_merged <- grid %>% left_join(l, by = c("id"="iteration")) %>% 
  mutate(score2 = (A*A_prop + B*B_prop))
```

The test that score and score2 are the same:

```
transmute(l_merged, identical = score == score2)

  identical
1      TRUE
2      TRUE
3      TRUE
4      TRUE
5      TRUE
6      TRUE
```

**Now to the actual problem**

I have adapted your code a little bit. I have added the iteration number to the output.

```
magic_for(print, progress=FALSE,silent = TRUE)

for(i in grid$id){
  score<-(dt$A*grid[i,1])+(dt$B*grid[i,2])
  A<-dt$A
  B<-dt$B
  iteration <- rep(i, 3)
  print(score)
  print(A)
  print(B)
  print(iteration)
}

rest<-magic_result_as_dataframe()

magic_free()
```

Now, if we look at the output and compare `i` and `iteration`, we can see that these are not identical. Therefore your `left_join()` has produced a confusing result.

```
rest %>% arrange(i)

  i score A  B iteration
1 1  11.0 2 20         1
2 1  22.0 4 40         1
3 1  13.8 3 30         2
4 2  16.5 3 30         1
5 2   9.2 2 20         2
6 2  18.4 4 40         2
```

To finalise, we can test it:

```
grid %>% left_join(rest, by = c("id"="i")) %>% # using i for the join
  mutate(score2 = (A*A_prop + B*B_prop)) %>% 
  transmute(identical = score == score2)

  identical
1      TRUE
2      TRUE
3     FALSE
4     FALSE
5      TRUE
6      TRUE
```

The join with `i` does not produce the correct results.

But the join with `iteration` will:

```
grid %>% left_join(rest, by = c("id"="iteration")) %>% # using the "manually" produced iteration for the join
  mutate(score2 = (A*A_prop + B*B_prop)) %>% 
  transmute(identical = score == score2)

  identical
1      TRUE
2      TRUE
3      TRUE
4      TRUE
5      TRUE
6      TRUE
```

I am not sure why the `i` from "magicfor" is different from the manually created `iteration`. I certainly get your confusion...

Comment: Hello,
Many thanks for your detailed and very clear explanation.
Also thanks for letting me know how I should pose my next questions.

Thanks again